# Hide Options from Mutiple Select box using Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, hide

I need to hide certain options from Multiple selection box using Javascript.
I can't got for jQuery, and I am not allowed to.

I have one more dropdown box, I am calling a js function which will be called upon change of the value. The js function will control the options of another multiple select options box, where I need to hide (not remove) options based on dropdown box value.

Any simple js function?

http://jsfiddle.net/zz3dg/

Comment: Set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle), or at least post some code.

Comment: did you try to use: fastInternet.options[i].style.display= 'none'; to hide the option?

Answer (score 0):

Select and option elements are notoriously hard to style. While you could try setting

```
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
```

on the options you wish to hide, I wouldn't expect universal support (even among CSS/JS supporting browsers).

Answer (score 0):

From what I've tried, `display:none` works in FF but not in Chrome... I tried `visibility:hidden|collapsed` (and a variety of other alternatives) and that didn't produce the desired results in Chrome either.  `visibility:hidden` hides the text but does not collapse the blank rows as I'd hoped.

I think the only workable solution in Chrome is to detach the `filtered` option elements (and that seems like a lot of work ATM)